# How to find foreign keys to tables which contain an arbitrary column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to find a set of tables which contain:

- a foreign key constraint to a specific table, and
- another arbitrary column name.

I'm using:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'MyTable'
```

This returns all of tables with foreign key constraints to 'MyTable', but I would like to do additional filtering.

As I have a particularly large list of resulting tables to work with in my database, I would like to filter the `FKTABLE_NAME` by tables that contain an arbitrary column name, for example `CreatedOn`, which is not necessarily itself the linked column.

Comment: This question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Something like this? 
`SELECT acc.table_name, acc.column_name, acc.constraint_name, cnst.owner, 
       cnst.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns acc
  JOIN all_constraints cnst ON acc.owner = cnst.owner
                        AND acc.constraint_name = cnst.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON cnst.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND cnst.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE cnst.constraint_type = 'R' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will look for tables that contain a FK to "yourtablename" where the referencing table has a column "yourcolumnname"

```
SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
   ,*
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'yourtablename' 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.name='yourcolumnname' AND c.object_id=f.parent_object_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a list of columns in the below. You can then select distinct table name and apply any other filters you need.

```
--build your temp table with output of SP_FKeys

    CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    PKTABLE_QUALIFIER  VARCHAR(100),
    PKTABLE_OWNER   VARCHAR(100),
    PKTABLE_NAME  VARCHAR(100),
    PKCOLUMN_NAME  VARCHAR(100),
    FKTABLE_QUALIFIER  VARCHAR(100),
    FKTABLE_OWNER  VARCHAR(100),
    FKTABLE_NAME      VARCHAR(100),
    FKCOLUMN_NAME       VARCHAR(100),
    KEY_SEQ INT,
    UPDATE_RULE  int,
    DELETE_RULE  int,
    FK_NAME  VARCHAR(100),
    PK_NAME  VARCHAR(100),
    DEFERRABILITY int
)
--Populate it
INSERT INTO #Temp
EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = N'Department'  
    ,@pktable_owner = N'HumanResources';  

--Now, join to systables and syscolums
    SELECT * FROM #Temp TEMP JOIN sys.tables ST ON TEMP.FKTABLE_NAME = ST.name 
    JOIN sys.columns SC ON ST.object_id = SC.object_id
    WHERE SC.name = 'CreatedOn' --enter your column name here
```